# How can I tell if I can increase RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB on my FSC Amilo XA 3530 Laptop?

Tags: memory, upgrade, ramdisk

I want to increase my laptop speed and use a ram disk but my RAM size is very low. How can I tell if I can increase my RAM from 4 GB on my FSC Amilo XA 3530 laptop? The specs stats it is DDR2 800Mhz Ram. Would a DDR2 667Mhz PC2-5300 SO-DIMM 200pin fit this box?

lspci -vvv:

```
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor DRAM  
Controller [1022:1302]
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-
Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- 
<PERR- INTx-
```

Comment: open it up or download cpuz and check it out

Comment: @Shark: I can download or open but what can use a lspci to verify?

Comment: try lspci -t  ,it shows grouped pci hardware, am not on a linux box at the moment. add the output of lspci here so one can have a look at it

Comment: @Shark: The specs stats it is DDR2 800Mhz Ram. Would a DDR2 667Mhz PC2-5300 SO-DIMM 200pin fit this box?

Comment: @Shark: I've add the information you have requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a shot and I bought a cheap 4GB DDR2 PC-5200 So-Dimm and my bios is showing me 6144 MB ram and I can boot into Windows 7. But if I knew this before I would have bought a PC-6400 because it's faster.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the specifications for this laptop. According to the [information](http://www.lapspecs.com/wiki/fujitsu+amilo+xa3530) I could find, this laptop can only use a MAX of 4GB of DDR2 800MHz.

Answer (score 2):

Crucial and SATech.com both report that 4GB is the hardware limit for the FSC Amilo XA 3530.

You could try a SSD replacement for your spinning disk and see if that helps performance.

The ***first*** thing to do for performance improvement is to profile to find out where the bottlenecks (if any) are located.  In other words, what leads you to believe a RAM disk will significantly speed up your execution?